# How to access static functions from inside a class member function?

Tags: f#

I have a unit test class:

```
type [<TestFixture>] BetTests()=
[<Test>]
  member x.HasGoodOddsTest() =
    let ret = HasGoodOdds 10.0
    Assert.IsFalse(ret, "Expected false");
```

and a static method defined outside of the class:

```
let HasGoodOdds odds = odds &gt;= 20.0
```

but I'm getting a compiler error: "The value or constructor 'HasGoodOdds' is not defined."

What's the syntax to get outside of the scope of the class?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is HasGoodOdds defined above the BetTests class?  Is it defined in the same file?

It needs to be defined above it (in a prior file, or above it in this file - generally you can't reference entities in F# until after they are defined), and if the BetTests class is not defined in the same module, you need to either use a qualified name (as @Vitaliy says) or use an 'open' declaration to bring the namespace/module into scope.

Answer (score 1):

This method should be defined in a **module**. Use `Namespace.ModuleName.Method` convention